# Find $\operatorname E(X\mid Y)$ given that $X=U+V$ and $Y=UV$ when $U$ and $V$ are independent with exponential distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

I currently have a problem with a problem set I'm working.

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are independent with exponential distribution with parameter $A$ ($T$ is exponentially distributed with parameter if its density is given by $A\exp(-At)$ for $t>0$).

Define $X=U+V$ and $Y=UV$.

Find $\operatorname E(X)$, $\operatorname E(Y)$, $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$, $\operatorname{Var}X$ and $\operatorname E(Y\mid X)$.

I think I managed to find everything except for $\operatorname E(Y\mid X)$. I know that $\operatorname E(Y\mid X)$ is equal to the integral of $yf(y\mid x)\mathrm dy$ and that $f(y\mid x)= f(y,x)/f(x)$ so I need to find $f(y,x)$.

Problem is I'm not sure how to find $f(y,x)$. I tried using Jacobian transformation and ended up with V/A and I'm not sure if I did it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shortcut is to note that $X=U+V$ and $Y=UV$ hence $Y=U(X-U)$ and that, conditionally on $X$, $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,X)$, that is, $U=XW$ where $W$ is independent on $X$ and uniform on $(0,1)$. Thus, $Y=U(X-U)=W(1-W)X^2$ and $E(Y\mid X)=X^2E(W(1-W))$ where
$$
E(W(1-W))=\int_0^1w(1-w)\mathrm dw=\frac16,
$$
that is,
$$
E(Y\mid X)=\frac{X^2}6.
$$
On the long road, one computes the conditional density, based on the standard change of variables $(U,V)\to(X,Y)$, since
$$X\gt0,\quad0\lt Y\lt\frac{X^2}4,\quad U,V=\frac{X\pm\sqrt{X^2-4Y}}2.$$
The Jacobian is $\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\sqrt{x^2-4y}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$ and two points $(U,V)$ are mapped to the same point $(X,Y)$ hence the density of $(X,Y)$ is
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{2A^2\mathrm e^{-Ax}}{\sqrt{x^2-4y}}\,\mathbf 1_{x\gt0}\,\mathbf 1_{0\lt4y\lt x^2}.
$$
Thus, for every $x\gt0$,
$$
f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{2}{x\sqrt{x^2-4y}}\,\mathbf 1_{0\lt4y\lt x^2},
$$
and $E(Y\mid X)=u(X)$ where, for every $x\gt0$,
$$
u(x)=\int yf_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\mathrm dy=\int_0^{x^2/4}\frac{2y}{x\sqrt{x^2-4y}}\mathrm dy=\frac{x^2}8\int_0^{1}\frac{z}{\sqrt{1-z}}\mathrm dz=\frac{x^2}6,
$$
hence
$$
E(Y\mid X)=\frac{X^2}6.
$$

Comment: I don't seem to fully understand the answer. For example where did U=XW come from? And for E(Y|X) how come we simply take X^2 out? and how did you determine that X > 0 and 0 < Y < X^2/4 ?

Comment: Sorry In addition how did you get U,V as well when doing the standard change of variables way?

Comment: Woa... is that all? :-) Actually, each of your questions is answered in my post except the first one, which is a standard exercise: if U and V are i.i.d. exponential then U/(U+V) is uniform on (0,1) and independent on U+V. If you never saw this result, then use what I call the long road. In the change of variable X=U+V, Y=UV, simply note that U and V are the roots of the polynomial T^2-XT+Y.

Comment: Yeah I'm more interested in understanding the long road. I don't know how you derived the polynomial or why y is less than X^2/4. Furthermore where did z come from?. edit: okay I understand why y is less than X^2/4. I'm just curious how we got the polynomial. and z.

Comment: Change of variable $y=zx^2/4$ (what else?).

Comment: how did we get the polynomial? I don't see how we can get U V as roots of the polynomial.

Comment: Note that U and V are the rots of T^2-(U+V)T+UV=0, always.

Comment: I guess, I'll try working on it.

Comment: *roots $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: what do you mean the jacobian dxdy? I can't seen to get your jacobian for some reason.

Comment: Which one do you get?

Comment: I got zero? I really don't know what i'm doing. I tried to create the jacobian matrix with du/dx du/dy dv/dx dv/dy

Comment: I just don't know how you got the jacobian and how you derive f(x,y). However after that I can kinda see how to proceed.

Comment: Show the matrix you get.

Comment: this is the matrix I got. I hope you don't mind imgur. I still have some problems using mathjax overall. http://i.imgur.com/v2NyNb2.png

Comment: There is a sign mistake since dU/dx and dV/dx cannot coincide. Once this is corrected, take the determinant and you will get the formula in my post.

Comment: I just drew a graph and you're right, I'll give it a shot again. Thanks for putting up with me though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Okay good news, I managed to get the jacobian and f(x,y). Bad news. I didn't get the the 2 in your f(x,y).

Comment: The jacobian i got was (1/sqrt(X^2 -4y)). g(u,v)= A^2 * exp( -A( u + v) ) which is A^2 * exp(-AX). I don't see where I can get the 2.

Comment: As is mentioned in the answer, the factor 2 comes from the fact that the map $(u,v)\to(x,y)$ is 2-to-1.

Comment: I don't think I understand why or how though.

Comment: You could try to compute the distribution of Z^2 when Z is uniform on (-1,1), there is also a factor 2 and the reason is the same: applying correctly the Jacobian/change of variable thing.

Comment: I'm sorry for being dumb but I still don't get it.

Comment: Dumb or not, did you compute the distribution of Z^2 when Z is uniform on (-1,1)? What is your result?

Comment: the density I got was 1/(4*sqrt(y)) with Y=Z^2

Comment: And you can see this density is incorrect since it integrates to 1/2. Let me suggest to fully understand this case (for example, using PDFs) before going back to your 2-dimensional question here.

Comment: I get 1/(2*sqrt(y)) when x is uniform on (0,1). I don't understand why i get a different answer when its (-1,1).

Comment: To know why you got a wrong answer, we need to know *exactly* what you did to solve the uniform(-1,1) case.

Comment: well I let y=Z^2 and find the distribution of P(Z < sqrt(y) ).  Which is equal to the integral[-1,sqrt(y) ] 0.5 dz. As a result I got sqrt(y)/2 + 1/2 as the distribution. The density was then 1/(4*sqrt(4)). This was done using a method shown in class.

Comment: Your last comment is completely offtrack. Let us restart from the beginning: let Z be uniform in (-1,1) and Y=Z^2, then Y is almost surely in (0,1) and, for every y in (0,1), [Y<y]=[-sqrt(y)<Z<sqrt(y)] hence...

Comment: Oh my god I'm such an idiot/ It's 1/(2*sqrt(y))?